# Pressing enter on webfrom throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, webforms

I am using a form in asp.net i has many button , i want that when i press enter than it should trigger SAVE button by default but when i press enter on this page then it throws error:

```
 The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

[image]

CODE:

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="#FF3300" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Name is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <label>Address</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Address is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <label>Contact</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtContact" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="#FF3300" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Contact is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <label>Complainant Type</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropdwnCompType" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" AutoPostBack="false" />
          <br />
          <br />


    <span id="Save-Span">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave"  CssClass="btn btn-success"  runat="server" Text="Save" 
         ValidationGroup="Complaints" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </span>
```

.cs

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveComplainant(); //calling a function which saves values in db being entered in textbox
    }
```

Update: this line should work surely but not sure that where to put it i page.

```
this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSave.UniqueID;
```

Comment: Do you have a javascript that listens for the "Enter" key?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property [DefaultButton](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_panel_defaultbutton.asp) of your Panel control to you button id.

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSave" ... > ... </asp:Panel>
```